# How to change MUI datagrid display mode for mobile viewport

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, responsiveness, mui-x-data-grid

I'm using MUI datagrid (community edition, v.5.17.22) in my react project (v.18.2.0).
I want to change how datagrid renders rows and columns when using the application on mobile devices. I don't know how to describe it better, so I attached two images of what I mean.
[image: Desktop viewport]

[image: Mobile viewport]

Is there any way to do that or I have to write my own component?
I searched the web, I checked many different react datagrids but non of them had such an option.
Also if you know any other datagrid with that option, please let me know about it.

Thank you all :)

I checked Bootstrap datatable, react datagrid (reactdatagrid.io), AG grid (ag-grid.com), CloudTables datatable (datatables.net) and some other datagrids. All of them didn't change the view in mobile device and just add a horizontal scrollbar to the grid.

Answer (score 0):

You can create 2 datagrids, one for desktop, one for mobile.